# Reading Input-frames from PreviewHighSpeedCamera callback method onCaptureCompleted() using Camera2

Tags: android, android-camera2, camera2

Reading Input-frames from PreviewHighSpeedCamera callback method  onCaptureCompleted() using Camera2

We are trying to set camera preview for more than 120fps i.e PreviewSessionHighSpeed using Camera2 API, below is the code snippet

```
private void updatePreview() {

    if (null == mCameraDevice) {
        return;
    }

    try {

        setUpCaptureRequestBuilder(mPreviewRequestBuilder);
        HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("CameraPreview");
        thread.start();
        List<CaptureRequest> mPreviewBuilderBurst = mPreviewHighSpeedCamera.createHighSpeedRequestList(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build());

        mPreviewHighSpeedCamera.setRepeatingBurst( mPreviewBuilderBurst, new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback(){
            @Override
            public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {

                super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);

                // We want to read the captured image buffer here
                // We tried to use ImageReader but highSpeedCameraSession doesnnot support ImageReader surface
                // HighSpeedcameraSession only supports preview or recording surface
            }

        }, mBackgroundHandler);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

We are able to set camera preview frame for PreviewSessionHighSpeed , but not  able to get frame buffer after OnCaptureComplete().

Any one know how to get frame buffer after OnCaptureCompete() ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The constrained high speed recording session is very constrained (thus the name); there's no support for application access to the high-frame-rate data - it can only be sent to the video encoder.

The preview is also only 30fps, so a SurfaceTexture cannot be used here either to get high-speed data.

Only devices that list high frame rates in their regular target FPS ranges support more flexible outputs; as of today, I'm not aware of any such devices. High speed recording is very much at the edge of mobile phone capabilities today.